# Reference a Sheet and Cell for use in Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a workbook where I want to reference a range in the first Sheet (B1) for the input of a formula in a cell in the second Sheet (B3). My problem is the first Sheet's name will always change so I thought to get around this I would create a variable based on the cell reference that the formula could use.  This is what I have so far:

```
Sub GetCellAddress()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim CellAddress As String
Set Cell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2)
CellAddress = Cell.Parent.Name & "!" & Cell.Address(External:=False)

With ActiveSheet
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = _
    "=CONCATENATE(""Balance Sheet"","" - "",MID(CellAddress,FIND("" "",CellAddress,FIND("","",CellAddress)+2)+1,256))"
End With

'MsgBox CellAddress

End Sub
```

Although the MsgBox will confirm the CellAddress I have is Sheet1!$B1$1 I cannot seem to pass this reference in the formula by just using CellAddress as I get the #NAME? error when I use it. 
If I use Sheet1!R[-2]C as the ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 syntax, it works fine but as I explained before I want the code to resolve the Sheet name. Either I have the wrong syntax or maybe my method is the incorrect way of referencing a range in another sheet. Can anyone show me where I am going wrong.

Comment: I've never seen a comma (e.g. `,` ) in a cell address, external or otherwise.

Comment: It is the string within that cell that has the comma i.e Best Hooper Financial Management Report Printed as at Fri, 25 May 2018 that I am obtaining the date from.

Comment: If is use 'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=CONCATENATE(""Balance Sheet"","" - "",MID(Sheet1!R[-2]C,FIND("" "",Sheet1!R[-2]C,FIND("","",Sheet1!R[-2]C)+2)+1,256))"'  it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying out the solutions above I used the following syntax:

```
 Sheets(2).Range("B3").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""Balance Sheet"","" - "",
 MID(" & Sheets(1).Name & "!B1,FIND("" "", " & Sheets(1).Name & "!B1,
 FIND("","", " & Sheets(1).Name & "!B1)+2)+1,256))"
```

which seemed to address the issue I had with referencing the sheet. So, it was just a matter of putting quotes in the right place when using @asleedawg 's Index method.

Care must be taken if the Sheet has spaces in the name. If it does, then add a single quote around the double quote referencing the sheet name.

Comment: Note that using the sheet index is just as dangerous as using the sheet name.  Just as the user can change the name of a sheet, they can also change to position of a sheet, which changes its index (eg by dragging the sheet tab).  Safest method is to use the `CodeName`

Comment: True, @Chris this could happen yet knowing my client and the particular project it is unlikely....however, I get your point and will consider altering the formula.

Comment: Just realised that after researching and testing the `CodeName` method that you can only reference it from a module within that specific workbook. Because I get the user to run the macro from a Personal.xlsb macro (this is because the workbooks are all different when they are sent to my client), referencing the `CodeName` will not work yet the Index and Sheet Name methods will.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem may be due to the syntax of cell address. If you ref cell A1 from 'sheet space' in 'Sheet1', you should get:

`='sheet space'!A1`

Notice the sheet name is wrapped in " ' " when the sheet name has a white space in it. When the sheet name is a single-word, the " ' " gets auto-formatted away, but is still a valid ref (i.e. `='Sheet1'!A1` is valid)

Try:

```
CellAddress = "'" & Cell.Parent.Name & "'!" & Cell.Address(External:=False)
```

Comment: Hi @Yeile, All this gets me is `'Sheet1'!$B$1` rather than `Sheet1$B$1` yet the formula still does not like the variable.

Comment: @MartinHewittTayler, your formula is compounded, so it can be difficult to identify the cause of your error. Can you try ```ActiveCell.Formula = CellAddress``` to see if you get a valid reference (i.e. ActiveCell returns the value at CellAddress, and not Error)? Update me on the outcome!

Comment: the cell address is `'Sheet1'!$B$1` when run with your code however, if you see my latest post I have solved the syntax error with using the index of the sheet.

Comment: Alright Sir, good that your issue have been resolved. Do consider Chris' comment on your reply, ```CodeName``` will be robust then using index

Answer (score 0):

### Using worksheet index numbers instead of names:

As I understand it, at least part of your issue is that you need to be able to refer to a worksheet even though the name of the worksheet will be changing at times.

You could refer to the worksheet's **index number** instead of it's name.

This temporary sub will list the names and index numbers of your existing worksheets in the Immediate Window:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

```
Sub CheckIdx()
   Dim ws as Worksheet
   For Each ws In Sheets
     Debug.Print ".Index=" & ws.Index,".Name=" & ws.Name,".CodeName=" & ws.CodeName
   Next ws
End Sub
```

The index numbers won't change when the name does.

If  you have a sheet named "data" with an index number of 3, you could refer to it either by name:

```
Sheets("data")
```

...or, by number:

```
Sheets(3)
```

---

### Edit:

As @Chris pointed out, Worksheet `Index` numbers *do* change, for example if the order of the worksheet tabs is changed.

**This can be prevented** by [protecting the **workbook**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/protect-a-workbook-7e365a4d-3e89-4616-84ca-1931257c1517) (with or without a password), by clicking:

- <kbd>**Review**</kbd> → <kbd>**Protect Workbook**</kbd> → *(Only "Structure" should be checked)* → <kbd>**OK**</kbd>
- Password not necessary but is optional.   [Protecting the **workbook** structure](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/protect-a-workbook-7e365a4d-3e89-4616-84ca-1931257c1517) prevents users from adding, moving, deleting, or hiding/unhiding worksheets, and is **not** the same as [protecting the **worksheet**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6), so cells can still be edited, etc.

  [image]

---

Another method would be to use the [worksheet `CodeName` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-codename-property-excel) instead of `Index`.  Technically this *can* also be changed but is less likely.

I've updated the `CheckIdx` function (above) to inlcude `CodeName`, so if you wanted to go this route.

Comment: Hi @ashleedawg, tried the Index method with the syntax being    ActiveCell.Formula = _
                "=CONCATENATE(""Balance Sheet"","" - "",MID(Sheets(1)!$B$1,FIND("" "",Sheets(1)!$B$1,FIND("","",Sheets(1)!$B$1)+2)+1,256))" but still got an Applicaton-defined or Object-defined error. Perhaps my syntax is wrong??